# Xamarin Forms - Prevent webview from loosing focus on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I'm trying to create an editor using Xamarin Forms.
The editor is a webview with content editable and a toolbar below.

You can check my current implementation [here](https://github.com/carlos-ferreira/bug-reports/tree/master/Xamarin/Webview).

It works well on Android, when i tap on the button, it executes the javascript on the webview,the keyboard remains open and the webview doesn't loose focus.

On iOS the webview looses focus and the keyboard closes.

Like this:

[image]

Any idea on how can i solve this ?

**What i tried so far:**

- Attach to the buttons an effect that calls ResignFirstResponder.
- On the content editable, call focus when bluring.

Comment: From the viedo , the webview looses focus and the keyboard closes when which button clicked? Also you can show some code about this logic,it will be helpful.

Comment: Done @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Okey , i will check that !